# why get method jquery run twice when loading next page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, get

i need help in this code must return posts in second page and append them to $container, but when **( if ) condition** is true , it returns posts twice like in next image.
What could be wrong?

```
$(window).off('scroll').on('scroll',function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() === $(document).height()) {
        var $more = $('.page-more-link')
        var $container = $('#time-line');
        
        ///// Before loading new items ////
        $('.get-more-posts').hide();
        $('.loading').show();

        $.get($($more).attr('href'), $.proxy(function(data) {
            var $data = $($.parseHTML(data));
            var $newMore = $data.find('.page-more-link');
            
            var $items = $data.find('.post');
            if (!$items.length) {
                   $items = $data.filter('.post');
               }

            $container.append($items);

            if (!$newMore.length) {
                   $newMore = $data.filter('.page-more-link');
               }
            if ($newMore.length) {
                $more.replaceWith($newMore)
                $more = $newMore
            }
            else {
                   $more.remove();
            }
            ///// After loading new items ////
            autosize_textarea();
            $('.get-more-posts').show();
            $('.loading').hide()
            /// count views of posts fun /////
            countViews($($items).find('.post-body'));

        }))

    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Do you notice a page resize that could adjust the scroll content? What I am thinking is that your page might grow a bit at the loading phase and, when the html adjusts itself, it also scrolls itself a bit, triggering your JS listener

Comment: Do you realize scroll fires multiple times? You do not have anything that checks it if it currently loading.